# Chi square and gamma distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Def: X has chi-square distribution with r degree of freedom if it has a gamma distribution with $\theta=2$ and $\alpha =\frac{r}{2}$, i.e. $f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{r}{2})} 2^{\frac{r}{2}} x^{\frac{r}{2}-1} e^{\frac{-x}{2}}$, x>0. This is abbreviated by saying $X \sim\chi^2(r)$.

How is Chi square different than Gamma distribution in problem solving?

Comment: You are correct that each chi-squared distribution is a special case of a gamma distribution. What makes chi-squared distributions interesting is that they occur (e.g., in statistics) as sums of squares of independent standard normal random variables.

Comment: It is look like this:  Uniform $(0,1)$ distribution is special case of beta $(a,b)$ with $a=b=1$ (also beta is special case of Dirichlet ) so what ....  another example: Exponential distribution is special case of ......  I think All of this because we develop(extend)  them again and again.

Comment: @masoud I see, thanks for drawing connections